# Query to find next distinct value in descending order very slow

Tags: performance, ms-access, duplicates, distinct

I have the following query to get the next distinct value from Access 2010 DB in descending order.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Top 1 Date FROM Timeseries where Date < #2016-05-13# ORDER BY Date DESC
```

Timeseries = table;
Date = field;

It returns the next value, in this case 2016-05-12 but takes a long time to run. The table is quite big with many duplicate date values. I also added an index to the date field.

Is there a more efficient way to run this query?

Comment: How does the performance of this query compare to what you have now?  `SELECT Max(t.Date) FROM Timeseries AS t WHERE t.Date < #2016-05-13#;`

Comment: @HansUp - selecting the max value is *significantly* faster than than distinct (due to large number of duplicates). Thanks!